# Git Clone from GitHub over https with two-factor authentication

Tags: git, authentication, github

I recently began using two-factor authentication on GitHub, and I am now unable to use git over https on private repos in the usual way:

```
peter@computer:~$ git clone https://github.com/[...]/MyPrivateRepo
Cloning into 'MyPrivateRepo'...
Username for 'https://github.com': [...]
Password for 'https://[...]@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/[...]/MyPrivateRepo/'
```

If I disable two-factor authentication I can use it as before:

```
peter@computer:~$ git clone https://github.com/[...]/MyPrivateRepo
Cloning into 'MyPrivateRepo'...
Username for 'https://github.com': [...]
Password for 'https://[...]@github.com': 
remote: Counting objects: 147, done.
remote: Total 147 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 147
Receiving objects: 100% (147/147), 22.70 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (87/87), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I know I can use SSH and everything works, but is there a way I can keep two-factor authentication while still being able to use GitHub over HTTPS, for example by sending an auth token with my request?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Find out how to fix this here:

https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication#how-does-it-work-for-command-line-git

> ### How does it work for command-line Git?
>
> If you are using SSH for Git authentication, rest easy: you don't need to do anything. If you are using HTTPS Git, instead of entering your password, enter a personal access token. These can be created by going to your [personal access tokens page](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Comment: You can add the token to the .netrc file as I found in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/wikimatze/9790374#use-netrc-file-to-store-credentials), to make authentication automatic too.

Comment: But I'm using ssh,when pull from github,it also hints me to input password and username,why this?thanks for your reply!

Comment: still its not working for me after entering the access token in mac
after sudo git clone.... system is asking for username and password in password field I am entering token but its not working for me. getting same error

Comment: Use your token as your username and give a blank password.

Comment: Mind the trailing *extra space* when manually copying the token from github site (i.e. if not using the github copy button). Took me a while to understand why this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 51):

As per [@Nitsew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305980/1023074) answer, Create your [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and use your token as your username and enter with blank password.

Later you won't need any credentials to access all your private repo(s).

**Updates 2021:** *(It worked for my M1 Mac)*

Create new Personal Access Tokens (Tick the appropriate boxes to grant permissions).
Use `GitHub username` and password as your `Personal Access Tokens`

[image]

Comment: Where would you recommend storing the access token on a remote server?

Answer (score 12):

To everyone struggling, what worked for me was creating personal access token and then using it as a **username AND password** (in the prompt that opened).

Comment: NICEEEEEEE!!!!!

Answer (score 9):

It generally comes to mind that you have set up two-factor authentication, after a few password trials and maybe a password reset. So, how can we git clone a private repository using two-factor authentication? It is simple, using access tokens.

**How to Authenticate Git using Access Tokens**

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Click Generate New Token button on top right.
3. Give your token a descriptive name.
4. Set all required permissions for the token.
5. Click Generate token button at the bottom.
6. Copy the generated token to a safe place.
7. Use this token instead of password when you use git clone.

Wow, it works!

Answer (score 5):

1st: Get personal access token. https://github.com/settings/tokens
2nd: Put account & the token. Example is here:

```sh
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com':            # Put your GitHub account name
Password for 'https://{USERNAME}@github.com': # Put your Personal access token
```

Link on how to create a personal access token: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If your repo have 2FA enabled. Highly suggest to use the app provided by github.com 
Here is the link: https://desktop.github.com/

After you downloaded it and installed it. Follow the withard, the app will ask you to provide the one time password for login. Once you filled in the one time password, you could see your repo/projects now.

Comment: only helps if you use windows

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.to/fpeluso/how-to-clone-a-gitlab-repository-after-enabling-2fa-6oc

```
git clone https://oauth2:{PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN}@github.com/[...]/MyPrivateRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update:** I found it easy to install [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/).
Simply install the cli and run `gh repo clone <repo_account_name>/<repo_name>`, which is available on the repository page.