# Why does `yarn install` hang when fetching packages on CentOS?

Tags: javascript, git, centos, yarnpkg

When attempting to install the dependencies for my project with Yarn via `yarn install`, the process (and progress bar indicator) hangs when attempting to fetch packages. A timeout never occurs and the `--verbose` option gives no useful clues regarding the cause of the problem.

CentOS 7

Yarn version: 0.27.5

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused by the combination of the older version of Git installed by Yum on CentOS (1.8.3.1-6 at the time of this writing) and Git's two-factor authentication mechanism.

Git's 2FA is the reason the hanging occurs in the first place, since one of the packages Yarn was attempting to fetch was a private repo via HTTPS ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305945/git-clone-from-github-over-https-with-two-factor-authentication#31305980)).

The version of the Git client in CentOS turned out to be the reason the hanging continued to occur and never timed / erred out. That is, the aforementioned version of Git on CentOS prevented Yarn from recognizing the authentication error and exiting accordingly.

The solution is to upgrade Git to a more recent version using a different repo:

```
sudo yum -y erase git
sudo rpm -U http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install git
```

This will stop Yarn from continuing to hang, with an output similar to the following:

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

My coworker and I had a similar issue and it was hanging because the vpn had disconnected. So double check your vpn is connected.

Comment: yes. that is the correct answer. I reconnected the VPN and the issue is gone!!!